# When I close my Java program it refreshes everything

Tags: java, swing

```
Label.setEnabled(true);

if (i == 0) {
    Label.setEnabled(false);
}
```

If `i` is equal to 0, it would not be enabled but when I close the program and open it again, it will be enabled instead of staying disabled.

Comment: By "close and open it again" do you mean, you halt the program (losing all non-persisted state) and then run another instance of it?

Comment: runtime changes do not persist unless you provide a means of doing so, which I'm assuming you have not.

Comment: You're not persisting the state of the value anywhere, so why do you expect it to be persisted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the current state of the program to a File. See [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java) on how to do that. Then, when you run the program, it needs to read from that file. You can do that like this:

```
File f = new File("PATH TO YOUR FILE");
try {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    String line1 = s.nextLine();
    String line2 = s.nextLine();
    //...
catch (IOException e){}
```